# ExampleData[] and Options[] in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

Has anyone been able to use these functions in Mathematica 8? They return nothing for me.

Comment: How did you call them?

Comment: Also make sure that M8 is set to connect to Internet.

Comment: It can connect to the Internet. I am calling them like so: ExampleData["Geometry3D"]

Comment: Maybe you have a firewall problem? I've had that once with our office firewall that used a rare brand of authentication that Mathematica didn't handle (NTLM). I used the CNTLM proxy to let Mathematica talk to this firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage Sample:

[image]